# Unable to parse String to Date type in iOS swift 3

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse String to date but getting nil value for some specific date.

The parsing of `2017-04-21 09:00:00` Tis successfully, but getting nil  value for string `2017-05-30 23:00:00`.

Here my code:

```
   func checkingDate(date: String) -> Bool {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
    let now = Date()

    if let currentData = dateObj {

        if (currentData >= now)  {
            print("big")
            return true
        } else if currentData < now {
            print("small")
            return false
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you setting the locale to `en_GB`? If anything, you need to use `en_US_POSIX`, at least when parsing the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `hh` as the hours specifier. That's a 12-hour value, and "23" clearly falls outside that range. ("09" parses because it's in range.)

Use `HH` instead:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: thank you Jon Skeet

Answer (score 1):

use uppercase H for 24 hour time lower case h is 12 h

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dateformater to **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**. HH is used to show 24h.

```
 func checkingDate(date: String) -> Bool {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

        let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
        let now = Date()

        if let currentData = dateObj {

            if (currentData >= now)  {
                print("big")
                return true
            } else if currentData < now {
                print("small")
                return false
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```